# JavaScript setTimeout() function not working on the "onsubmit" form attribute

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout, onsubmit

I am very new to JavaScript so apologies if I am missing something obvious.

I am trying to display a hidden div upon form submission but instead of having it displayed immediately it needs to appear with a slight delay (e.g. 3 seconds).

I have tried using the setTimeout() function on the 'onsubmit' attribute but the hidden div appears immediately and not with a delay.

Here is a minimal example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>When you submit the form, a function is triggered which alerts some text.</p>

  <form action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="setTimeout(myFunction(), 3000)">
    Enter name: <input type="text" name="fname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <div id="message" style="display: none">Loading...</div>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block"
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Also available here:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G3Y3E1YISNH1

So to summarise, `setTimeout()` is running myFunction but not with the expected delay. I'd be really grateful if someone could help me get my code right please! Thanks.

Comment: Try `"setTimeout(myFunction, 3000)"` (without parentheses). Or `"setTimeout(() => myFunction(), 3000)"`

Comment: You will most likely need to use `event.preventDefault()` too to stop the `form` default action of posting.

Comment: Ah did you change the accepted answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use modern JS conventions. On the JS side, not the HTML side, find your form, and use event listening:

```
let form = ... // there are many easy ways to get this element

form.addEventListener("submit", evt => {
  // don't actually submit this form to its associated URL:
  evt.preventDefault();
  // and schedule the timeout
  setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Many thanks for this :) The div now shows after a few seconds as expected however the form stops being submitted as a result... Is there no way to achieve this so that the div is displayed while the form is being submitted at the same time? Removing "evt.preventDefault();" seems to prevent the div from showing altogether. Clearly I have a lot to learn!

Comment: yeah: you can call `form.submit()` manually to force it to go through whenever you're ready for that to happen. The `evt.preventDefault()` stops the event from doing "whatever it normally does", which in this case is loading a URL immediately because you specified an `action` attribute. `form.submit()` will make that submission happen when you need it to.

Answer (score 3):

You have to send a function to do a function. Either use:

```
onsubmit="setTimeout('myFunction()', 3000)"
```

Or use this way:

```
onsubmit="setTimeout(function () { myFunction(); }, 3000)"
```

Also, for not making the form submit, you may try doing a `return false`:

```
onsubmit="setTimeout(function () { myFunction(); }, 3000); return false;"
```

And please use unobtrusive method by using `addEventListener`.

Comment: But really, don't use inline-js in an `on...` attribute in 2019.

Comment: given their level, it's safe to assume they don't know what that means, though ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are executing the function during assignment. Remove the brackets `()`. You actually need to pass the reference to the function as a parameter. When adding brackets, you are executing the function and then passing the return value of the function as a parameter.

```
<form onsubmit="setTimeout(myFunction, 3000)">
```

Furthermore, you should also not use `onsubmit` and inline assignments altogether. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56094317/3233827) for more information.

Comment: I believe the form will still submit since the function will execute once the time is up which is too late to stop the form submitting so adding `event.preventDefault();` or `return false;` to the `onsubmit` attribute should work. `<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault();setTimeout(myFunction, 3000)">`

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the myFunction instead of passing the function as callback to `setTimeout`. 
change it `setTimeout(myFunction(), 3000)` ---> `setTimeout(myFunction, 3000)`

Thanks